# R - how to clean REGEX in a more efficient way

Tags: r, function, data-cleaning

guys.

I am a beginner in R and have been experiencing some hard times trying to make a data cleaning code more efficient.

I basically have a tibble with several columns with REGEX characters ("R$" and ",") and I need to remove them in order to successfully convert those columns to as.numeric.

I could figure it out how to clean it column one by one, but the result, as you can see, its a lot of repeated code:

```
clean$total_amount <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", clean$total_amount, fixed = TRUE))
clean$net_amount_received <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", clean$net_amount_received, fixed = TRUE))
clean$fee_gateway <- as.numeric(sub(",", ".", clean$fee_gateway, fixed = TRUE)
```

and so for more 10 columns...

I've tried functions and lappy functions, but nothing worked. Could you help me with that, please?

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
clean  <- clean %>%
        mutate_at(vars(total_amount, net_amount_received, fee_gateway),
          str_replace, pattern = ",", replacement = ".")) %>%
         type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

---

But, this could have been prevented while reading the data itself with `read.csv` with specifying the `dec`

```
clean <- read.csv('file.csv', dec = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```